# Git: Compare 2 branches in different remotes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I'm using [Heroku Pipleines](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-pipelines) to deploy from a staging environment to production, and want to write a script which compares the two remote repos to see if there are any pending migrations. So I need something along the lines of:

```
git diff staging/master..production/master
```

with a filter to check the `db/migrate` directory.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The man page says the syntax is:

```
git diff [options] <commit> <commit> [--] [<path>...]
```

In your case this means:

```
git diff staging/master production/master -- db/migrate
```

Comment: The OP's `X..Y` syntax was *also* correct (has the same meaning); he just needed to add the `-- <path>` filter.  Either way this is the right answer though.  Just remember to `git fetch` the remotes as needed.

Comment: I tried this but get and error: fatal: bad revision 'production/master'

Comment: What is the output of `git branch -r`? Do you have a remote named "production" and a branch master there?